# Build an WiFi IP camera with webcam

Tags: usb, wifi, camera

I have a USB webcam and a WiFi module which it can convert Serial data to WiFi and vice versa.

The question is can I simply convert the data coming from the webcam to serial with a USB to Serial IC (like FT232R ) and then hand it over to my WiFi Module?

Answer (score 1):

Not even close. USB-to-Serial ics are usb peripherals (slaves), like the web cam. Without something in between, like a usb host (i.e., a computer) you could not get the two to talk.

Comment: you know I want to put my webcam on a robot. and my robot wants to move around my house and I want to see the webcam images with my computer. so I want to somehow convert my webcam to a WiFi IP camera. do you have any suggestion?

Comment: Attach webcam to Raspberry Pi. Install "motion" on Pi. Plug USB Wifi dongle into Pi.

Answer (score 1):

Simply put, no. The bandwidth required for a webcam will be much larger than you could sensibly put over serial.  OK I know you can get >2MBaud of out an FT232R (with a suiteable RS232 Line driver), but that will still absolutely prevent video and make still images slow.

Fundamentally the USB Camera is a device and must connect to a USB host.  The WiFi module (from the information you give) is not a USB host.

If you obtain a [Raspberry Pi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raspberry_Pi), you could probably use that as it is a USB host to which you can connect your camera and an ethernet (or your WiFi) module.  (I only say probably as you didn't give the make/model of camera, so I don't know if suitable software is available for the Pi)

Comment: you know I want to put my webcam on a robot. and my robot wants to move around my house and I want to see the webcam images with my computer. so I want to somehow convert my webcam to a WiFi IP camera. do you have any suggestion?

Comment: I'll suggest the Pi again, that could control your robot too. I've updated my reply with a link to the Pi if you are not familier with it.

Comment: @Jasom I hadn't heard about it. How can I get started with it? Shall I install linux on this device?

Comment: There's lots of enthusiast sites about development of both hardware and software with the Pi, it usually comes with Linux already installed.  I suggest you start with Google.  P.S. If you find my answer useful, please upvote it!

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't do it that way. You will need a USB host that interfaces to the webcam and sends the data over Wi-Fi.

This would be quite simple to do with a Raspberry Pi if your webcam is supported by Linux (those days, most are, I believe).